# currency converter in java

Tags: java, javac

I'm currently learning how to use java and every time i try to input this mess of a code it says:

> incompatible types: possible lossy conversion from double to int

I was simply wondering why this error is occurring and how can I fix it.

```
public class currencycoverter {    
    public static void main (String[] args) {        
        int  suma , sumb ,sumc , answera , answerb , answerc , a , b , c , d ;

        a = 1.00      ;
        b = 0.697443  ;
        c = 1.08901   ;
        d = 135.090   ;

        suma = a * 100 / b ;
        sumb = a * 100 / c ;
        sumc = a * 100 / d ;

        answera = suma   ;
        answerb = sumb   ;
        answerc = sumc   ;

        System.out.println ("euro 100 will buy ="+ answera) ;
        System.out.println ("euro 100 will buy ="+ answerb) ;
        System.out.println ("euro 100 will buy ="+ answerc) ;        
    }
}
```

Comment: You should read up on what an integer is.

Comment: Java isn't C: declare your variables where you first need them, e.g. `double suma = 1.00;` and `double suma = a * 100 / b;`.

Comment: Also the answer variables are unneccessary since they have the same values as the sums.

Answer (score 4):

An `int` is only capable of holding integer values. So in your code all the fractions are discarded. Your compiler is warning you about this: helpfully.

(Also note that if both arguments of a division are `int`s, then the division is truncated to an integral value *irrespective* of the type that receives the value.)

A simple fix is to replace `int` with `double` which can hold decimal quantities.

But that can be a poor choice for money values (research *floating point precision*). Consider using a currency type instead.